# small gearbox for experimental wind mill

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, applied-mechanics, mechanisms, wind-power

The gear box will have little torque as I am only using a 12 by 18" wing which rotates. The two shafts I am using are 1/4 ", one form the wing and the other going the to pivot for the wing to circle, with lift.  I can't find 1/4" gears and I am not sure how to attach them to the two shafts so that they cause rotation in different directions.  I know only two gears of equal size are needed, but I never made a gear box before.

I hope this helps.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: For gears perhaps try: https://www.pic-design.com/products/gears/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple "hack". get you a derelict cordless electric drill which contains a two-speed transmission. the transmission will gear up the blade shaft to spin the motor shaft at a higher speed, and you'll have two choices of gear ratios to best match the speeds of the two components.

Better still (!!!) the motor in the drill will serve as a convenient electric generator!  All you have to do is disconnect the variable-speed trigger control and route the motor wires out of the drill housing to your diode pack and battery arrangement. You'll need the diodes to prevent the generator from being driven like a motor by the battery.

On top of that, the drill chuck in the electric drill can be used as-is to grasp the propeller shaft without having to machine a custom coupling. You just stick the shaft into the chuck as if it were a drill bit and tighten it down.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I need a drawing to help describe the weird thing I am doing.  Two rotating wings, due to the wind, driving a generator....

Comment: you can reach me directly thru my website, www.nielsenkillowatt.com